# How to update a java file in an EAR project

Tags: jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 10.1. When I import an EAR project,all the jsp and js files are imported. But for java files, only class files are imported. I have some of the java files. If I want to make modifications in a java file, then how to build the new java class after making the changes.
Basically I need to know how to modify a java file in an existing EAR project(since only class files are there), how to create the new EAR after the change so that new class file is updated.

Would really appreciate if someone can help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a compiled class in an EAR. You have to build the EAR again, for which you need the java source files. If you don't have them (and can't get them) you are breaking the law (in most parts of the world).

Comment: Thanks. That means when I modify the java source file and build the new EAR then the new java class will automatically be created and and all I have to do is to replace the old EAR with the new EAR. I don't have to do anything to build the new java class. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.